# HttpClient().PostAsync() return 500 usually when deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I had problem when call api from this server to other servers. I used HttpClient().PostAsync() on c#. It works well on my local, but when I deploy it on my amz server, it worked very unstable. Below is my code.
I google and search on our forum but I still very confuse about my problem.

My scenario: Server A call to server B

This is code on Server A:

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      var ValueCollection = ....;
      var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(ValueCollection);
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(action,  formContent).Result;
      logger.Fatal("Line: 131 - : " + await      response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());                
      ...   do something else ...
   }
```

This is code on Server B - recive the request:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login-password")]
    public object Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel param)
    {
        logger.Fatal("Login with: " + param.username + " - pw: " +    param.password);
         ... Get user and return user.
    }
```

As you see, I added log on two methods, but when it return user, the log can work, and when I get error, I didn't see the log on server B, and log of server A is [ "Line: 131 - : " + [page 500] ] - its mean the return is error 500.

I log-in, log-out, about 10 times, it is fail up to 4-6 times. I don't know why ...

Note: It's work about 10 times on my local.

I removed [form body] but it's still happen.

Can someone help me to explain for this case ?

Regards,

Howie

Comment: Have you checked the logs on server B? It's the one generating the 500.

Comment: Yes, I checked. Server B has no any log, so I think they have something wrong between them that i can't explain.

Comment: I think server B didn't receive any request in that moment.

Comment: Well a 500 error is being generate by something. Are you sure your url is correct? A 500 is being generated by the server your HttpClient is connecting to. If it didn't connect you'd have a socket error not 500

Comment: As I mention, it not wrong 100%, sometime it's wrong. if the url is not correct, it cannot work at least once.